# Config files editable after `npm run build`

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm deploying a web app using react-redux soon and I was wondering if it was possible to let the user using the production version to modify a config file so that he can set his own initial settings.

Is it possible, after I run `npm run build`, to have a *config.js* file in the *build* folder that the user can go and directly modify?

If not, is there any better way to accomplish that using another strategy?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct you want to expose a API to change some of settings in config for end user and then somehow restart your API servers to apply those changes.

Always a dangerous way of doing things. You can expose functionality to change few of fields of config for end user and when applied restart the node process. There are few ways to restart node process from code itself or writing a hot script which monitors changes in source directory.

But beware its risky thing to do. Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually it wouldn't change any values in the API, only the value on the client-side. For example, I have a timer with a `2500` default value. If the user wishes to change that value, he/she can open the `config` file and change it to `3000`. The app would then have a timer with 3000 as its value when it opens.

Comment: So you do not need to restart api servers when timer changes ?

Comment: No the timer triggers an action on its own, so the value in it would just trigger the action at a different time

Comment: To use the new timer value after the user changes it, he would only need to restart his application

Comment: @petithomme you found any solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately no... I always have to rebuild the app if I want to modify these configurations. For development I don't mind, but for a user that simply uses the built application, it eould really be useful.